# How to avoid Okhttp certificate pinning byepass using SSL trust killer application?

Tags: android, security, ssl, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using okhttp3 certificate pinning for security. But VAPT  team able to bypasses the pinning and able to intercept the communication. They are using android ssl trust killer apk.

**Code for building the pinner object:**

```
public CertificatePinner provideCertificatePinner() {

        final CertificatePinner.Builder builder = new CertificatePinner.Builder();

        builder.add(DOMAIN_PATTERN, "sha1/***********");

        builder.add(DOMAIN_PATTERN, "sha256/**********");

        builder.add(DOMAIN_PATTERN, "sha256/*******");

        builder.add(DOMAIN_PATTERN, "sha256/*****

        return builder.build();

    }
```

**Attaching pinner to HTTP client:**

```
OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient(HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor, CommonRequestInterceptor authenticationInterceptor

            , CertificatePinner certificatePinner) {

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = null;

        try {

            OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout

                    (Constants.NetworkConstants.READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS).connectTimeout

                    (Constants.NetworkConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            okHttpClientBuilder.sslSocketFactory((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());

            okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(authenticationInterceptor);

            okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(interceptor);

            okHttpClientBuilder.certificatePinner(certificatePinner);

            okHttpClient = enableTls12OnPreLollipop(okHttpClientBuilder).build();



        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return okHttpClient;

    }
```

Comment: I don't think trying to protect against attacks on rooted devices is worth the effort. If the device is rooted, you have already lost the local battle.

Comment: For checking root I am using https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer and its rootBeer.isRootedWithoutBusyBoxCheck() method.

Comment: You can check root using software, and the attacker can figure out what software you're using to check for root and can fool it. I'm afraid there's no technical solution here, the only way to win is to do more work to obfuscate your code than the attacker is willing to do to deobfuscate. And don't pay the VAPT team, they didn't do anything.

Comment: As laalto already pointed out on rooted devices you can not prevent reverse engineering. Therefore you have to design your protocol between Android and the server this way that it does not matter if someone can reverse-engineer it and see the data.

Answer (score -1):

You can see [this blog series](https://approov.io/approov-in-detail.html) about a fictional App to see all security steps you can take to protect your App, how they can be bypassed and in the end you will be able to see how the back-end can defend from communicating with a compromised App.

So in short the bypass of certificate pinning cannot be avoided, but the back-end of your App can defend against it.

Despite certificate pinning can be bypassed is still recommended to use it as 1 more layer of defence.

Another important thing to protected against compromised Apps and/or devices is to have your App communicating only with back-ends you have direct control, avoiding direct calls to third part service providers as much as possible.

(Disclaimer: I work at [Approov](https://approov.io/approov-in-detail.html), the solution to protect against compromised Apps, that is referenced in the blog series I linked to.)